# Simplifying the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to follow a textbook's simplification of an answer, but I can't quite grasp the following step. Why does this series sum in the following way? $$\left(\frac12\right)^2 + \left(\frac12\right)^4 + \left(\frac12\right)^6 + ... = \left(\frac12\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac12\right)^2}\right) = \frac{1}{3}$$ I can't see why the series simplifies in this way.

Comment: It's a geometric series with quotient $q = \frac{1}{2^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:
Let $$S=\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^4}+\frac1{2^6}+\cdots$$

$$\implies 4S=1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^4}+\frac1{2^6}+\cdots$$

On subtraction, $4S-S=1$

---

Alternatively,

In fact, this is an [infinite Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) with the first term $\frac1{2^2}$ and common ratio $=\frac1{2^2}$

So, the sum $$=\frac{\frac1{2^2}}{1-\frac1{2^2}}$$